# Java percentage difference logic with polarity

Tags: java

I am trying to create a percentage difference between two values - I need to a) ensure the presented value is correct - like if its +35%, or 250%, -25% b) deciphering if its a positive or negative change.

[image]

```
float thisPeriod = 10;
float lastPeriod = 8;

float percentage = (float) (thisPeriod/lastPeriod) * 100;
System.out.println("percentage " + percentage);

String polarity = BasicUtils.checkPolarity(percentage);
System.out.println("polarity " + polarity);


public static String checkPolarity(float difference){
    if(difference == 100) return "positive";

    if(difference < 100){
        return "negative";
    }else {
        return "positive";
    }
}
```

-- Scenario 1
this period - 10 members
last period - 8 members

```
So there is a +25% difference. (125-100?)
```

-- Scenario 2
this period - 20 members
last period - 15 members

```
So there is a 33% difference. (133-100?)
```

-- Scenario 3
this period - 20 members
last period - 10 members

```
So there is a +200% difference. -- but then shouldn't this be 100% difference (200-100?)
```

-- Scenario 4
this period - 40 members
last period - 10 members

```
So there is a +400% difference. -- but then shouldn't this be 300% difference (400-100?)
```

--- is my logic correct here to obtain the kind of display?

Comment: also - I think I need a way of handling or preventing infinity values -- suggestions?

Comment: Why is 15 -> 20 "-33%"?

Comment: Scenario 3 and 4: Yes, those should probably be +100% and +300%.

Comment: @tobias_k -- I mean -- 33%

Answer (score 1):

You logic seems to be a bit off. If you want the change in percent relative to the previous value, I think it should be `difference / old_value`:

```
public static String percentageChange(double last, double now) {
    double delta = now - last;
    double change = delta / last;
    return String.format("%+.2f%%", change * 100);
}
```

Examples:

```
percentageChange( 8, 10);    // +25.00%
percentageChange(15, 10);    // -33.33%
percentageChange(10, 30);    // +200.00%
```

Answer (score 0):

The current period expressed as a percentage of the last period will always be

```
thisPeriod / lastPeriod * 100
```

So if `thisPeriod == lastPeriod` then this is 100, if `thisPeriod` is half of `lastPeriod`, you get 50, and so on.

The percentage *change* is, like you seem to already suspect, 100 percentage points less:

```
thisPeriod / lastPeriod * 100 - 100
```

We're subtracting 100 percent here, because we want to disregard the members who were already there in the last period. This is the same as expressing the *change* as a percentage of the last period:

```
(thisPeriod - lastPeriod) / lastPeriod * 100
```

Which of these two formulations you find more readable is up to you.